# TABLE in SQL with a constraint

Tags: sql, integer, constraints, varchar, identifier

I'm trying to create a table and one of my columns I want it to be a `cool_id` number that is limited to 7 characters. The first 3 characters must contain (1,2, or 3).

```
cool_id char(7),
```

I'm not sure how I'd go about specifying the constraint for it.

Comment: Create a custom id provider.

Comment: Depends on What your DBMS is, please tag your DBMS

Comment: Probably you'd refer to the documentation on constraints for the specific RDBMS you are using - you have not tagged it.

Comment: What version of what product?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, that depends on database you use. I speak *Oracle*, so - here's what you could do here (I hope other databases - your included - offer something similar): use a **check constraint**.

You said:

> ... cool_id **number** that is limited to 7 **characters**

What is it, then? A number, or a character datatype column? I presume latter (as you posted `char(7)` as well). In Oracle `char` is rarely used, mostly in cases when column is always fully filled with data; otherwise, column is right-padded with space characters which is kind of misleading if you don't know what you're doing. Therefore, perhaps you'd rather use `varchar2`.

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (cool_id varchar2(7) constraint ch_cid check
  3                           (substr(cool_id, 1, 1) in ('1', '2', '3')),
  4     name    varchar2(20)
  5    );

Table created.
```

Testing: this one works; the 1st character is `1`:

```
SQL> insert into test (cool_id, name) values ('1ABC7', 'Little');

1 row created.
```

This one won't work; the 1st character is `6`:

```
SQL> insert into test (cool_id, name) values ('6MNO123', 'Foot');
insert into test (cool_id, name) values ('6MNO123', 'Foot')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.CH_CID) violated
```

This is OK; the 1st (and only) character is `3`:
SQL> insert into test (cool_id, name) values ('3', 'Foot');

```
1 row created.
```

This would work if value length wasn't larger than 7 characters:

```
SQL> insert into test (cool_id, name) values ('2abcdefghi', 'Foot');
insert into test (cool_id, name) values ('2abcdefghi', 'Foot')
                                         *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-12899: value too large for column "SCOTT"."TEST"."COOL_ID" (actual: 10, maximum: 7)


SQL>
```